# Why is SQL Server ignoring emoji's in equals statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode, collation

Came across an interesting problem today and wanted to know the reasons behind the behavior. I have a users table with usernames and I query against that to pull the unique user out and then do password checks with all the hashing and salty goodness.

However, if I put emojis in the query, the user is still pulled out of the database and I'd like to know why and what setting need to be applied. I am using EF, but I tested the raw T-SQL and the behavior is the same so EF is not the culprit.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Users 
WHERE username = N'someuser' --Works as expected

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Users 
WHERE username = N'someuser' --ALSO WORKS!
```

I can put emojis anywhere and as many as I want and the user is still returned.  I can obviously put C# code in place that would do additional checks so this issue is solvable there, but I'd like it solved at the database level as there may be many other queries that do string comparisons.

Emojis in the password aren't a problem since hashing and salting will be applied in C# so emojis in a password are fine.

Comment: Whats the Collation set to for the Database?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: CP1 means [code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), I'd assume anything not in that code page is completely ignored.

Comment: @ErikPhilips that'd be my guess as well... while I don't know the specifics, by default the engine probably ignores anything not in it's known collation.  Try poking around in collation settings documentation/articles for clues.

Comment: C# uses Unicode by default, while SQL Server uses Latin-1 CP 1252 which similar to ANSI that ignores any unavailable set of characters. You need to change collation that supports specific Unicode format like Japanese_Unicode_CI_AS.

Comment: And `username` I guess is `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`

Comment: username is nvarchar. I'll play around with the collation and see if that works.

Comment: @ManOVision, An unrelated observation about your code: you said you are locating a user by username first and then checking password. If this is a web application then this is not a good practice as it allows an attacker to build a list of valid usernames by measuring response times on the "login failed" page. At the very least ensure that you always perform all hashing operations even if username is not found.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, the code posted is a very slimmed down version as there are more checks. I am curious about the response time monitoring so I will look into that. The login system in question is oauth-ish so there are also client id checks and lockout checks and the SSL handshake so there are other factors that would affect response time. I will definitely check this out. The main reason for C# to check rather than the database is because the collation is case insensitive. Also, I would need to index the password column which would add some insert/update overhead as well.

Comment: have you tried username= N'someuser'?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I did try that as well with the same results. It's definitely the collation, but I need to research more on what collation would work best or if I should just let c# do the comparisons.

Comment: The literal `'someuser'` does **not** have this effect. As it gets treated as `some??user??`. So I've changed your example to `N'someuser'` - which does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The collation that you're using doesn't support the comparison of the emoji characters; so it ignores them. You can use a specific collation during the comparison if you want things to work as you'd normally expect:

```
select *
from (values
    (N'someuser', N'someuser')
  , (N'someuser', N'someuser')
  , (N'someuser', N'someuser')
) as a (L, R)
where a.L = a.R collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC;
```

See the MSDN article [Collation and Unicode Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) for more info.

Comment: It doesn't seem to always work as expected even with specific collation. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326848/in-sql-server-why-is-n-equal-to-n